# How to play a music file from a url in cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

How can I play a m4a music file from an URL in cocos2d?

I try with SimpleAudioEngine:

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadBackgroundMusic:@"http://a1327.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/073/Music/v4/14/d7/9a/14d79aa4-53bb-d7be-e7d0-8f4f3f5d235d/mzaf_8740286426674526399.aac.m4a"]; 
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"http://www.mydomain.com/music.m4a"];
```

But don't works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cocos2d doesn't support url playing for now. What you can do is download the file to your device then play it use local path.

Comment: Do you know how can get the currentPlaybackTime of SimpleAudioEngine?

Comment: Never tried this before, but I don't think SimpleAudioEngine supports that or has a "pause" function.